Importing data in PostgreSQL database
I wrote the code below in PostgreSQL to create a table:
CREATE TABLE Tryy(
    Retailer varchar(45),
    Retailer_ID int,
    Dates date,
    Months int,
    Region varchar(45),
    States varchar(45),
    BeverageBrand varchar(45),
    Price_perUnit varchar,
    Unit_Sold int
);

This code runs successfully, however when I try to import the data it gives me this error.

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer: "Units Sold"
CONTEXT: COPY beverages, line 1, column unit_sold: "Units Sold"

This seems to be happening to all my data when I specify any other data type (Num, Int, Date) except when I use varchar. I am new to PostgreSQL and I need help to go around this.
I tried this for a small amount of rows in a table and is still don't seem to work with the INT, NUM and DATE datatype.

however when I try to import the data ... how are you importing the data and what does it look like?

Check out your firs line because it looks like it's trying to insert the column name as a row, since it's at line 1 it's 90% sure it's the problem.

More than 90%: The error is for line 1, it finds the text "Unit Sold" there. What else could it be but having column headers as the 1st line of the file?

Your copy statement is not correct, you don’t skip the header

Per COPY: COPY Tryy FROM some_file WITH CSV HEADER
